# Install the main application executable file to subfolder with Inno Setup Studio

Tags: inno-setup

I was using Inno Setup QuickStart Pack 5.5.6 and it was perfect.

I installed Inno 5.5.8 QuickStart Pack 5.5.8 and I'm having some problem.

If I start Inno Setup I can select appname, company and Ii can select path of the program and program exe file, so look this screen:

[image]

like you can see I selected the main .exe in \Binaries\Win32\  so it is located not in main folder of the program but in a sub-folder.

Now this is the code that I have

[image]

Inno Script studio automatically write the wrong exe path, it is not the main folder of the program but like I said already it is in `\Binaries\Win32\`.

But why it did this? I worked with Inno Setup QuickStart pack 5.5.6 and I never seen this problem, the correct path was correct also if the exe was in some sub-folder.

Answer (score 2):

You have these two entries in the `[Files]` section.

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\temp\Life Is Strange Episode 5\Binaries\Win32\LifeIsStrange.exe"; \
    DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\temp\Life Is Strange Episode 5\*"; \
    DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesudirs createallsubdirs
```

This does not make any sense. The entries overlap.

It seems you believe that by selecting the directory `C:\temp\Life Is Strange Episode 5` in the *"Other application files"* setting you somehow miraculously define a mapping between the `C:\temp\Life Is Strange Episode 5` and the `{app}` that should make Inno Setup Studio know that when you select the main application file  `C:\temp\Life Is Strange Episode 5\Binaries\Win32\LifeIsStrange.exe` it should go to `{app}\Binaries\Win32`. It won't. The entries are not related to each other in any way.

So, the first entry will install the `LifeIsStrange.exe` directly to `{app}`.

The second entry will install a whole directory tree, **including** the `LifeIsStrange.exe`.

So you end up with `LifeIsStrange.exe` both in the `{app}` and the `{app}\Binaries\Win32`.

But the icon will point to `{app}\LifeIsStrange.exe`.

I believe the Inno Setup Studio does what you asked it to do.

If you want it to do something else, you have to set up things differently. Though I'm not sure the Inno Setup Studio allows you to install the main application executable anywhere else, but to the `{app}`.

To do what you ask for, you probably have to edit the `.iss` manually to be like:

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\temp\Life Is Strange Episode 5\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; \
    Flags: ignoreversion recursesudirs createallsubdirs

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; FileName: "{app}\Binaries\Win32\LifeIsStrange.exe"
```